# How to increase number of points in matlab Graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two arrays `x` and `y`. Array `x` contains values 10,20,30,40,....1000. And array `y` contains some random value between 0 to 1. I plotted graph in Matlab then on x-axis it is pointing 100, 200, 300... 1000 only. So The analysis in graph seems to be not as expected. If x-axis contains point intervals with some less difference (here 100), then there may be a chance the outcome will be perfect. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab shows you x-ticks in a spacing that will be clear enough to read. You can set the spacing in X-axis ticks as you want with [`xticks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html?s_tid=doc_ta) (and the same for `yticks`), if you have Matlab 2016b or later, and with [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51413) command for earlier versions. Here is an example:

```
x = 10:1000;
y = rand(1,size(x,2));
plot(x,y,'o')
set(gca,'XTick',50:50:1000) % <- set the places where X axis have ticks
% xticks(50:50:1000) % in version 2016b or later
```

The result with the example above:

[image]

Comment: And also I am ploting graph using syntax plot(array1, array2)

Comment: That doesn't matter, it works with `plot` `scatter` or any else plotting function.